# How to get Powershell to recognise pscx modules?

Tags: powershell, windows-10

I installed powershell community extensions because I want to use `Show-Tree` for this code.

```
# Log project state
# Assumes CWD is the project file

$Tree = Show-Tree -ShowProperty -ShowLeaf | Where-Object {$_ -inotmatch '^.*Property.*' -or $_ -match '^.*LastWriteTime\s.*'}

$i = 0
$culture = [Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture

foreach($entry in $Tree){
    if($entry -notmatch '^.*Property.*'){
        $d =  "{0:hh}:{0:mm}:{0:ss}" -f ([DateTime]::Parse($($Tree[$i+1] -replace '^.+=\s(.+)','$1'), $culture))
        $Tree[$i] = "$d`t$entry"
    }
    $i++
}

$Tree = $Tree | Where-Object {$_ -inotmatch '^.*Property.*'}

foreach($s in $Tree){Write-Output $s}
```

This works OK in a PS debug session in VS Code but when I try to use it in MSBuild or with the powershell command prompt, it complains that it can't find the extension module...

```
Show-Tree : The term 'Show-Tree' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. At C:\Users\Admin\Documents\GitHub\powershell-scripts\ProjectSnapShot.ps1:6 char:9
+ $Tree = Show-Tree -ShowProperty -ShowLeaf | Where-Object {$_ -inotmat ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Show-Tree:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I checked the PSModulePath env variable and it is pointing to two valid loctions, one the std modules and the other pscx modules...

[image]

According to [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878324(v=vs.85).aspx#Anchor_2), this should mean the module is loaded automatically.

> Generally speaking, you can determine where you should install your
>   module by using one of the paths stored in the $ENV:PSModulePath
>   variable. Using one of these paths means that PowerShell can
>   automatically find and load your module when a user makes a call to it
>   in their code. If you store your module somewhere else, you can
>   explicitly let PowerShell know by passing in the location of your
>   module as a parameter when you call Install-Module.

How can I get this to work from the PS command prompt and when called from MSBuild?

Comment: Powershell is a session-oriented language. That said - it sometimes behaves differently when run interactively and from command line. It may run differently in different hosts. Some Powershell IDE's (not VS sadly) allow runspace reset which helps to get predictable results. In some cases - like type aliases caching - only reboot helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're having this problem when running the above code as a script, there are a number of things you can do, for example:

If you're only worried about this script running on your machine, you could pass `Import-Module` the explicit `.psm1` path of the module file containing the function `Show-Tree` before you assign the $Tree variable.

If you're looking for more portability, you could copy the code defining the function `Show-Tree` from the `.psm1` module file into this script, again, before you assign the $Tree variable.

If you're looking more to figure out *why* this is happening, here is the section on inheritance from the PowerShell help file `about_Scopes`:

> Inheritance
>
> A child scope does not inherit the variables, aliases, and functions from the parent scope. Unless an item is private, the child scope can view the items in the parent scope. And, it can change the items by explicitly specifying the parent scope, but the items are not part of the child scope.
>
> However, a child scope is created with a set of items. Typically, it includes all the aliases that have the AllScope option. This option is discussed later in this topic. It includes all the variables that have the AllScope option, plus some variables that can be used to customize the scope, such as MaximumFunctionCount.

Comment: But why does it run ok in the VS Code debug environment? I read that since (I want to say ver 3?) the modules are loaded automatically. So there's no need for an `Import-Modules` statement. And the module paths are there in the env variable. Why doesn't it work? The section you quoted reads like a monty python script (half a bee, philosophically, must IPOs-facto half not be...). And anyway, there is no shared scope between my code and the library. I don't understand how that's relevant...

Answer (score 0):

This problem was resolved after re-booting my computer.  There were some other strange instabilities (new errors being thrown despite nothing having changed) that also disappeared after the re-boot.

Answer (score 0):

I observed similar behaviour as well. Even if the GUI shows that PSMODULEPATH is ok, running processes (like explorer.exe) do not automatically pick up changes to the environment. Usually Log-Off/-On or a reboot helps.

Background:
When a process starts, the current environment is copied "into" the process. If a process starts another process, like if you start a program using Windows Explorer, the new child process gets a copy of the parent processes environment. Changes to the user or system environment variables are therefore not picked up by running processes unless the process explicitly listens to WM_SETTINGSCHANGED window message and reacts accordingly. From my experience not many processes do this correctly.

Comment: VS Code must start a new process for every debug run and my powershell session wasn't closed between runs, so that would explain that. The only thing I still don't get is why MSBulid threw. I call it from a target that is imported into my 'csproj` file. I guess it must be caching an instance of ps for the whole session.